# Create a single line from a resultset of line segments

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

How can I create a single line using the line segments geometry found in each row in resultset?

I followed this tutorial: http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/

I found roads in a route from point A to point B.
This roads are rows in a resultset and now I need to create a single line from point A to point B representing the entire route.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213026/postgis-function-to-connect-geometry-line-together

Comment: My comment doesn't qualify as an answer, just up-vote the answer you found over there. (You could also seek out some useful answer of mine somewhere and up-vote it i suppose.)